# Show that a function from an interval to a metric space is constant

Tags: real-analysis

We have $f:I \to Y$, where $I$ is an interval in $\mathbb R$ and $Y$ is a metric space with a distance function $d$. The function satisfies the following condition:

$$ d(f(x_1),f(x_2)) \le C|x_1-x_2|^p , p \in (1,\infty), C \in \mathbb R$$

I need to show that $f$ is constant.

if $Y$ were a vector space with a norm, then I would argue that the derivative of $f$ in each $x_0 \in I$ is zero (because $\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{d(f(x_0),f(x))}{|x_0-x|} \le \lim_{x \to x_0} C|x_0-x|^{p-1} = 0$) and thus $f$ is constant.

But in our case $Y$ is a metric space...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an arbitrary $n$, let $y_k = x_1 + k \frac{x_2 - x_1}{n}$. Then

$$d\bigl(f(x_1), f(x_2)\bigr) \leqslant \sum_{k = 1}^n d\bigl(f(y_{k-1}), f(y_k)\bigr) \leqslant C \sum_{k = 1}^n \lvert y_{k-1} - y_k\rvert^p.$$

Finally, let $n \to \infty$.